# errors while trying to use users.nitro discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
    @client.command()
    async def nitro(ctx):
        nitro = ctx.message.author.discord.profile.nitro
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f":house_with_garden: {ctx.message.author} - Stats",
                              description=f"Nitro: {nitro}",
                              color=discord.Colour.green())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Whenever I run this I get this error :

```
"discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'discord'"
```

I want this to say if a user has nitro when I type: .nitro @username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ctx.message.author.profile().nitro`, as discord.Profile is a class representing a user's profile (accessible through Member.profile).

Comment: I now get this error: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'nitro'

Comment: @Frenology Actually, it doesn't look like you can do this. I checked the docs and it says that only non-bot accounts can access profiles.

Comment: Can it get user badges eg: hypesquad etc?

Comment: Yes, using `ctx.message.author.public_flags`. I don't know much about what this attribute has, so look at [the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.PublicUserFlags).